# How to open a modal poppup window in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my java script code:

```
    <script> 
    $('#<%= btnOpen.ClientID %>').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').modal({ onOpen: function (dialog) { 
     dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () { 
      dialog.data.hide();
      dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () { 
      dialog.data.slideDown('slow'); 
     }); 
    }); 
   }, 
   onClose: function (dialog) { 
    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () { 
     dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function () { 
      dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () { 
       $.modal.close(); // must call this! 
       }); 
      }); 
     }); 
    }  
  }); 
 </script>
```

And my button

```
  <td> 
   <asp:Button ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
  </td>
```

at this situation on click of button only page is refresh

Comment: Return false inside your script to cancel postback of button.

Comment: you dont need to do like this:  $('#<%= btnOpen.ClientID %>')
when you set ClientIDMode Static, just simply do  $('#btnOpen')

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this link :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:scriptmanager>

<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Button" />

<cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"


cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" okcontrolid="btnOkay" 
targetcontrolid="Button1" popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" 
backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
</cc1:modalpopupextender>

<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
<div class="HellowWorldPopup">
            <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">Header</div>
            <div class="PopupBody">
                <p>This is a simple modal dialog</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Controls">
                <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
                <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to restrict postback:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding in a **document ready** statement

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    //rest of your script here
});
</script>
```

Another thing to mention is **if you know the specific id of your button** just reference it as such

```
$('#btnOpen').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of your script here
});
```

End result:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnOpen').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if(!HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]){
                //userID exists show form code
                //rest of original code here
            } else {
                //do something else or nothing
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Comment: I want to open modal-popup login.aspx when session user-id is null else want to perform another action

Comment: Okay, then I would recommend this approach as I tend to try and stay away from dumping server code into my javascript. (see revised answer)

Comment: You want to be able to extract your javascript to a separate file eventually so there is no need to dump <%= btnOpen.ClientID %> in the script.

Comment: I want to call a logincontrol.ascx in if part,how to do this